# window. onload=function() just works without cached DOM

Tags: javascript, wordpress

The product image is displayed as inline SVG and receives a new color for specific paths, depending on the dropdown selection.

```
"use strict";
window.onload=function(){

var dropdownColor = document.getElementById('Color');

// When a new <option> is selected
dropdownColor.addEventListener('change', function() {
var selectPathSvg = document.getElementById('pathNumber');

//get value text
var colorValue= selectElemFerse.options[selectElemFerse.selectedIndex].text;

//Clear all Classes from SVGPath
selectPathSvg .classList = '';

// Add that class to the <p>
selectPathSvg.classList.add(colorValue);
})
}
```

But this Javascript code works only, if the page was read in the DOM for the first time. If you reload this page with F5, this will not lead to any errors in the console, but not to the desired result.

EDIT: Nothing here worked for me. But I noticed that if I delete the `woocommerce_recently_viewed``cookie, that the systems works fine. But how to fix such a thing?

Comment: How is the script being included?

Comment: By `but not to the desired result` do you mean that the function is not being run or that the svg is not displayed properly?

Comment: It's included with `wp_enqueue_script`.

Comment: And the function is not being run and so the colors of the svg are not shown properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally bad practice to use `onload = ...`
 You should instead try using `addEventListner("load", ...)`

The reason your script does not run, is because it gets compiled after the page has been fully loaded, so you should **also** check if the load event has already been fired.

```js
"use strict";

if(document.readyState === "complete") onLoad();
else addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onLoad);

function onLoad(){
 console.log("Doing on load stuff here...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead and see if it works:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    var dropdownColor = document.getElementById('Color');

    // When a new <option> is selected
    dropdownColor.addEventListener('change', function() {
        var selectPathSvg = document.getElementById('pathNumber');

        //get value text
        var colorValue= selectElemFerse.options[selectElemFerse.selectedIndex].text;

        //Clear all Classes from SVGPath
        selectPathSvg .classList = '';

        // Add that class to the <p>
        selectPathSvg.classList.add(colorValue);
    })
});
```